# How to interpret Google Earth Engine's aspect output (ee.Terrain.aspect)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

The `ee.Terrain.aspect` function produces a raster of aspect values in degrees ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-terrain-aspect)). How are the values interpreted? For example, are the cell values (degrees) measured from north? or east? Do values increase clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: For aspect definition see https://geographicalanalysis.com/gis-blog/dem-slope-aspect-hillshade/

Comment: @TomazicM The link you provided is to one convention for aspect raster products. Do you know if Earth Engine follows this convention? And not the 'trigonometric angle' (0 = east and 90 = north) convention for example?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with GEE.